# get buffer contents, store it in struct, get new buffer contents see if equal in struct

Tags: c++, c, arrays, struct, comparison

I've been learning c++ for about a couple months now...I made a smaller program to see where I'm going wrong in a bigger program....

I'm taking information from a buffer[] and storing it in a struct. When the buffer's information changes, I want to check in the struct to see if it's different from the previous data received.

I am stumped, any ideas?

I can see that the array lengths are the same, when i print the contents, they appear to be the same in the console. I want to say it's with my compare function? or it's how i'm saving the data to the struct?

Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

struct _tag
{
    char tagValue[25];
    string tag;
};
_tag tag;

int isTagValueEqual(char* input, char* output){
    if (input == output)
        return 1;
    else return 0;
}

void get_tag(char* input, char* output)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        if (input[i] == 0x20 || input[i] == ' ')
        {
                //output[i] = '\0';
            //fill remainder of array with 0s
                for (int j = i; j < 25; j++){
                    if(j==24)
                        output[j] = '\0';
                    else 
                        output[j] = ' ';
                }
                break;
        }
        else
        {
            output[i] = input[i];
        }
    }
}

int main(){

    char buffer[] = "248:-22:119:-23:18:-60 -71";
    char raw_tagValue[25];
    //initialize to 0
    *tag.tagValue = 0;


    get_tag(buffer, raw_tagValue);
    cout << "raw_tagValue: " << raw_tagValue << endl;

    //sscanf(raw_tagValue, "%[^0]", tag.tagValue); // copy char array
    //strncpy(tag.tagValue, raw_tagValue, strlen(raw_tagValue));
    strcpy(tag.tagValue, raw_tagValue);

    //check to see if raw_tagValue is equal to itself
    if (isTagValueEqual(raw_tagValue, raw_tagValue) == 1)
        cout << "works" << endl << endl;
    else
        cout << "doesn't work" << endl << endl;

    // compare raw_tagValue to tag.tagValue
    if (isTagValueEqual(tag.tagValue, raw_tagValue) == 1)
        cout << "works" << endl;
    else{
        cout << "doesn't work" << endl;
        cout << "tag: " << tag.tagValue << endl << "rawTag: " << raw_tagValue << endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem:

```
if (input == output)
```

That  just compares two pointers, not the contents of what they point to.

Use:

```
if (strcmp(input, output) == 0 )
```

**PS** There might be other problems in your code.